# How to encrypt some data and store in html markup?

Tags: asp.net, encryption

I have an asp.net page i do authentication and authorization of a user and user can make several ajax requests from this page. What i want to ensure is that the request only from this page so i will store some data(or token)(possibly a function of userID + user IP address + current time) encrypted in the page aswell as in the session so the requests that come with this token will only get served. Does anybody have any idea of doing this? Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store it in the [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188774.aspx). You will then need to send the value of the ViewState hidden field along with your AJAX request.

Comment: what i want is know how to encrypt the data?

Comment: @Jishnu, ViewState is encrypted, so storing your data there will automatically encrypt it.

Comment: But i want the encrypted data to be accessible via javascript and send data everytime the user makes some  ajax request to webservice. and check whether the token is valid by comparing it with the data that i have stored in session.

Comment: @Jishnu, ViewState is stored in a hidden field inside the DOM thus accessible through javascript.

Comment: It seems okay... but it'll also have unnecessay data(may be even kbs) .. is it okay?

Comment: Yes indeed there is additional data which you might not need. As an alternative to ViewState you could encrypt the data using [FormsAuthentication.Encrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.encrypt.aspx) and then decrypt it with [FormsAuthentication.Decrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.decrypt.aspx). In order to perform the encryption those methods use the machineKeys in machine.config so make sure they are the same if you are running in a web farm.